# Which differential protocol to use when redriving Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, differential, reverse-engineering, protocol

I want to redrive a 100-BaseTX signal on a board. The signal is to be redriven 3 times (by the same setup). On one end is a STM32 NUCLEO-F767ZI board, and on the other end is a GbE switch including the Vitesse VSC7429, which has 12 integrated PHYs.

When looking at an application note from Wurth ([here](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/media/o179578v410%20SN016a%20EN.pdf)), I saw the 2 ways to use Ethernet isolation tranformers : VML and CML. I went on to look at the NUCLEO-F767ZI schematics :
[image: Nucleo PHY]
And it seems to be wired in CML mode, according to Wurth's appnote (the transformer's middle point is connected to +3V3). However it doesn't exactly fit what Wurth shows (mostly on the 50 ohms pull ups), which confuses me.

On the other hand, here is Vitesse's Media Interface :
[image: VSC7429 Media interface]

It corresponds to Wurth's VML schematic. I'm not sure the resistors shown inside the PHY are the 50 ohms series resistors, but I'll consider they are.

I went on to look at specialized ICs to redrive Ethernet, but found there are very few with this specific role. On Texas Instruments' DS100BR111A Datasheet, which is in their "Ethernet redrivers" section, it is shown to also be compatible with SATA protocol. The differential in/out pins are shown as "CML", and the layout recommendations indicate the pairs are to be AC-coupled. On another chip, the SN75LVCP600S, the inputs are listed as CML and the outputs as VML. I am so confused.

One important thing about Ethernet is inter-compatibility of devices, so I need to make it look like (to the GbE switch) it's directly interfaced with the Nucleo board, and vice-versa. So I need to reproduce what's happening beyond the magnetics. I think the setup [Magnetics <-> CML/CML repeater <-> Magnetics] should be transparent, but it's very heavy, and I'm looking for the minimal parts count.

**Question 1 :**
Does it matter ? I couldn't find info on the compatibility between the 2, and most appnotes and datasheets don't even bother with the VML/CML notion.

**Question 2 :**
Can I use a "simple" CML repeater ? I don't need the 10 Gbps, and would do fine with a smaller pin count.

*Note : I am not looking for component suggestions, I've simply included the ones I looked at to illustrate my confusion on the matter.*

Edit : Removed question about magnetics and included info about desired design characteristics

Comment: If you want indirect lightning surge protection isolation you need transformers. If you couldn't find something and it bothers you then yes, you should dig deeper.

Comment: What do you mean by redriving? You have standard RJ45 interface on Nucleo board with magnetics, so that is what you must use? If so, then you need standard RJ45 interface with magnetics on the switch side too. Only if both PHYs allow for capacitive coupled interface, and you can control both PHYs yourself, you can skip the magnetics on both ends with simply capacitors. But how would you connect to the Nucleo board PHY if you rip out the transformer and connector?

Comment: @Justme I need to connect the Nucleo board to the switch THROUGH 3 separate PCB boards, each connected to the other using RJ45 interfaces. I could simply route the signals in & out of the intermediary boards, but I want the option to redrive the signals on these boards. Sorry, that wasn't clear enough in the question.

Comment: @Harnex what is on those intermediate boards on the Ethernet lines? Are they direct connections between RJ45 sockets? Ethernet is specified to go 100 meters between two PHYs and their transformers. Why do you think redriving is needed?

Comment: @Justme I know Ethernet is specified to go for long distances, but there may be, in total, more than 100m with the distances between all the boards combined. So I want to be sure and add the option to redrive. On those boards are digital functions unrelated to the Ethernet link. If I choose not to install the redriving circuitry, then yes there will be a direct path between the RJ45 sockets on those intermediate boards.